# 12.04.01 upgrading from creating LiveCD

Tags: 12.04

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04.01 from the Ubuntu site and tried to make a LiveCD, LiveDVD, LiveUSB but while finishing burning it got some curruption. CD/DVD did not come out automatically. It says take it out mannually. When I pull out manually it shows some curruption occurred.

What is the correct way to create a LiveDVD or LiveUSB for upgrading my previous version. And what is the method to Upgrade with this LiveDVD or USB.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are already on 12.04, you don't need a liveCD to upgrade. Just update your question like you always do.

Comment: If you're not on 12.04, how are you burning the CD?  Did you also check the [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)?

Comment: But then it's clearly NOT upgrade. Use an alternate image or use the update manager

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should check your MD5SUM of the iso image to see if it is a corrupted download. See [HowToMD5Sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). Use UNetbootin to burn the ISO image. If you're using a CD/DVD, use a slower burn speed. However if you are to upgrade, use an alternate image and mount it, or just use the update manager, or use `sudo do-release-upgrade` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have made several CD and all of them became corrupted. Then I decided to write it on a DVD and I got success.
 
It seems my CDs or/and CD Writer have problem when the image size is near to the CD max size.